# Rabbi Elimelech of Lizhensk cancelled the Chevlei Moshiach?

Tags: messiah

[Given recent developments and the hot topic of the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2023_Israel%E2%80%93Hamas_war) a number of people keep telling me that Rabbi Elimelech of Lizhensk said that he cancelled the Chevlei Moshiach. How do we know this? What sefer is this written in? Who wrote the sefer and when? If Rabbi Elimelech did make these comments what was the context and what exactly did he mean?

I have read in Mesechta [Shabbos 118a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118a.7?lang=bi) that we can nullify the war of Gog and Magog and the Chevlei Moshiach and the judgement of gehinnom by eating the three seudahs of Shabbos. Is this Gamorrah connected to his claims in any way?

Comment: It seems to be mostly an oral tradition. I found a few references online but they're not reliably sourced: [1](https://tora-forum.co.il/threads/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%98%D7%97%D7%94-%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%91%D7%98%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A-%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%A7.185/), [2](https://youtu.be/rFU-2uJ4SH4), [3](https://www.dirshu.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%9C.pdf)

Comment: Doesn't seem like it

Comment: @wfb Reportedly the Belzer Rebbe didn't accept that the Holocaust was chevlei moshiach because of this.

Comment: Better not to write "recent developments and hot topic of the day" - in 2 years someone reading this won't know what you are referring to - just spell it out clearly please

Answer (score 2):

Here a just a bunch of collections from several seforim that discuss this concept.

See the sefer Igra Debe Hiluli  [אגרא דבי הילולי](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990021797830205171/NLI) (p. 235):

> בכל העולם סיגף עצמו במאד מאד וידוע שאמר כי ביטל בסיגופיו היסורים של חבלי משיח ואמר שפלא שחז"ל כתבו על חבלי משיח אם ידעו שיהיה מיילך קודם ביאת משיח צדקינו מדברי תורתו נודע לתהלה הספר הקדוש נועם אלימלך שהו"ל בנו הרה"ק ר' אלעזר זי"ע [(Otzar HaChochmah)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/53243/p/252/t/0.99180497870725381234/fs/HeiT0qb1OuUzT1YpsdZYLrWdSsDBEEEWtR01902kCytV/start/24/end/44/c)

See also sefer גינת ורדים - קובץ תורני לענייני הלכה ואגדה - יג:

> נד פע"א שאלתי את רבינו היות שנודע בין החסידים מה שאמר רבינו הקדוש בעל נועם אלימלך זי"ע שהוא בקדושת עבודתו כבר ביטל חבלי משיח ואיך היה כל אותן הצרות שסבלו אחינו בני ישראל בכל מדינות אייראפע בשנות הזעם משנת תרצ"ח עד שנת תש"ה השיב לי רבינו בזה הלשון וואס ווייסטו וואס וואלט געווען אהן דעם ןמה אתה יודע מה היה מבלי זאת [(Otzar HaChochmah)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/177000/p/74/t/0.99180497870725381234/fs/HeiT0qb1OuUzT1YpsdZYLrWdSsDBEEEWtR01902kCytV/start/200/end/204/c)

Maybe the clue of all of this above is that in the merit of all the Holy things the Noam Elimelech wrote, and the seforim he wrote, we can merit to have the troubles smoothen up (correct English?), as it is written:

> שכל הרהור תשובה שיש בעולם נמשך מכח הרר א זי"ע וכן מובא שהמתיק הרר"א בעבודתו הק וביטל את חבלי משיח [(sefer דעה חכמה לנפשך, p. 18, Otzar HaChochmah)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/654172/p/807/t/0.99180497870725381234/fs/HeiT0qb1OuUzT1YpsdZYLrWdSsDBEEEWtR01902kCytV/start/288/end/292/c)

Finally, see sefer [דרשות לחם שלמה (Otzar HaChochmah)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/163739/p/175/t/0.99180497870725381234/fs/HeiT0qb1OuUzT1YpsdZYLrWdSsDBEEEWtR01902kCytV/start/108/end/116/c)

> ואולי יש לפרש על פי מה שכתוב בפייט להושענא רבה יענו בשסקה תטענו בארץ ישראל השזינה ביד שבעה ושמונה ישר צדיק אל אמונה ומפרש המפרש הכתיב במיכה ה' שיהיה ז' רועים נשמונה נסיכים ובסוכה נ"ב חושב אותם בשמם יע"ש והנה מבואר בסנהדרין צ"ח דכמה אמוראי אמרו ייתי ולא איחמיניה מגודל הצרות וחבלי משיח שיהיה לפני הגאולה והצה"ק בעל נועם אלימלך ז"ל אמר שהוא ביטל חבלי משיח והיינו שפירר אותם שלא יהיו בפעם אחת ומסתמא כל הצדיקים מדור דור התפללו על זה שירחם ה' על עמו וישלח משיחו ברחמים וברצון לא על ידי צרות משונות וחבלי משיח וזהו התפלה טענו בשמנה תטענו בארץ הקודש על ידי שבעה רועים ושמונה נסיכי אדם ואף שצריך להיות צרות וחבלי משיח אבל אתה ישר וצדיק עשה לפנים משורת הדין לגאול אותנו ברחמים וזה גם כן מאמר שלמה המלך ע"ה על הגאולה העתידה שאמר לכל הדורות תן חלק לשבעה וגם לשמונה פירוש שתתפלל לה' לשבעה רועים

As I understand, the Noam Elimelech [would emphasise](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/640162/p/227/t/0.99180497870725381234/fs/HeiT0qb1OuUzT1YpsdZYLrWdSsDBEEEWtR01902kCytV/start/268/end/272/c) the need for unity for Klal Yisrael.

I also read (sefer gone in my search-results), that G-d planted righteous persons in each generation to give light in that generation. My own interpretation of this is that the Noam Elimelech would shine light into his generation, would pray for his generation, with the hope in ending Chevlei Moshiach and sweetening the judgement.

ps: for the one who is willing to translate the pieces, very welcome. I have trouble translating it by my own. Understanding it is easier for me :)

EDIT:
RabbiKaii had a wonderful addition to this. The Gemara in Yoma 38b says that planted (some) righteous people in the generations. Rashi (ad loc. Sv. וישת עליהם תבל) [writes](https://www.chabad.org/torah-texts/5446104/The-Talmud/Yoma/Chapter-3/38b):

> פיזרן בכל הדורות להיות שתות וקיום ויסוד לקיים תבל

The righteous persons in our generations serve like a fountain in which we can "drink from Torah", e.g. be sustained by it (my own interpretation).

(Normally, I cite from Sefaria, but I just discovered that Chabad.org has a great translation, including some great selections of meforshim on the Gemara).

Comment: Great answer and amazing sources. The source for planting the righteous in each generation is Yoma 38b, and is brought in the first perek of Tanya

Comment: Thanks for that addition and compliment. I added in the Gemara in Yoma. I hope I did not misinterpret these sources due to the fact that my Hebrew is still WIP.